# How to use multiple types in node-elasticsearch-client?

Tags: node.js, express, elasticsearch

I'm a newbie and working on an ES project (Express JS+ ES+MongoDB ). I'm using https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb to do the indexing. The following code is working fine for a single index and type. But I have another type with the same index name ("type" : "file_info"). Is there any way to use multiple types with the same index name ?
For example- var type= ["stu_info", "file_info"].

```
var index = "studentdb";
var type = "stu_info";
var elasticSearchClient = new ElasticSearchClient(serverOptions);

elasticSearchClient.search(index, type, qryObj).
        on('data', function (data) {
           console.log(data)

        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply concatenate the types with a comma:

```
var type = 'my_type,my_other_type,my_third_type';
elasticSearchClient.search('my_index_name', type, qryObj)
.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(data))
})
.exec();
```

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch.js API has **search** method.

type: String, String[], Boolean — A comma-separated list of document types to search; leave empty to perform the operation on all types.

[search Api][1]https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-search